# How to remove intersection of ideal $I$ and $J$ from union of ideal $I$ and $J$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, polynomials, ring-theory, ideals

after get the intersection of ideal $I$ and ideal $J$ 
how to remove this intersection from union of ideal $I$ and ideal $J$
in order to do prime decomposition

how can it do in maple?

actually i have calculated the intersection I and J
however, it is a complicated polynomial which are not any one polynomials in I or J

how to remove or complement it?

Please remember this remove that can make the result be prime decomposition

the intersection is Basis(w*I, (1-w)*J) and then remove polynomial which contain w

i also get wrong with union, you remind me that union is not just a simple set union

so how to correctly union two ideals in maple?

Comment: I think you are confused. Ideals are (usually infinite) sets, not polynomials, although a polynomial can generate an ideal (and Maple will present ideals by generators). And (in a polynomial ring) non-trivial ideals _always_ intersect non-trivially (a product of elements form either ideal is always in the intersection) so trying to "remove the intersection" is vain. And the union of two ideals is not an ideal in general (their sum is though). You should rethink what you really want to do.

Comment: you are right, i guess union is not the set union, so how to correctly union ideal I and J in maple?

Answer (score 1):

$(I \cup J) \setminus (I\cap J)$. If is the base ring is $R$, you can also write $(I\cap (R\setminus J)) \cup (J \cap (R\setminus I))$.

Comment: \ is set complement, it's just notation for removing one set from another. Maple lists it as set difference. See http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=union

Comment: i get it, how can it do in maple? i guess it is not a simple set problem just remove c from {a,b,c} because c is not contained in the list of I and J

Comment: If you don't have more structure on your ring, I don't see a more specific way to do it than just by set operations.

Comment: the intersection is Basis(w*I, (1-w)*J) and then remove polynomial which contain w